# is there a way to visualize Spark mllib Random Forest Model?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I can't seem to find a way to visualize my RF model, obtained using Spark's MLLib RandomForestModel. The model, printed as a string, is just a bunch of nested IF statements.. it seems natural to want to visualize like is possible in R. I am using Spark Python API, and Java API.. open to use anything that will produce an R-like visualization of my RF model.

Comment: What do you mean by visualizing the randomforest model? If you have it in R what are you looking for? `rf <- randomforest(y~., data) rf summary(rf)` I do not see an easy way of visualizing a Random Forest. A decision tree yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/10/27/visualizing-machine-learning-models.html) (Oct 2015):
"The plots listed above as Scala-only will soon be available in Python notebooks as well. There are also other machine learning model visualizations on the way. Stay tuned for Decision Tree and Machine Learning Pipeline visualizations!"

Answer (score 7):

There is a library out there to help with this, [EurekaTrees](https://github.com/ChuckWoodraska/EurekaTrees). Basically it just takes the debug string builds a tree and then displays it as a webpage using d3.js

Comment: How does one save just a string as a .txt from spark?

Comment: In python it is `model.toDebugString()` to get the string and then just use 
`f = open('debug.txt', 'w')`   
`f.write(model.toDebugString())`

Comment: @ForFunAndProfit - perhaps a late followup question - Should i convert the text to .json or other format? Because I get this error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'